# Ubuntu 12.04 wired connection keep disconnecting

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb, ethernet

I'm facing repetitive disconnections on a wired interface USB/Eth (EEM). I'm not sure the origin. How can I be sure it is or not caused by Ubuntu ?

My ethernet controller is (output of lspci):
Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)

And the USB one is :
Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)

The PC is a HP EliteBook.

What else can I check ? Do ?

Thanks for any hints...

Have tcpdump pcap file available - but cannot attach here...

Comment: Define "keep disconnecting"? Does your network manager tell you that the network was unplugged? Or internet just stops working?

Comment: Mmm, sorry, you're right. Not sure how to name it, but a small box appears on the top right corner and displays a message stating "Wire connection disconnected"..